# Nested API calls in PHP

Tags: php, api, nested

I am calling an API endpoint to get a list of domains:

```
/v2/domains
```

Within this result I need to make another call to get the domains details:

```
/v2/domains/{domainName}
```

This currently happens inside a `foreach` loop which makes the process time consuming and costly.

Simplified example:

```
$domainobj = $client->get('/v2/domains/');
$domains = json_decode($domainobj->getBody()->getContents());

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    $domaindetailobj = $client->get('/v2/domains/' . $domain->domain_name);
    $domaindetail = json_decode($domaindetailobj->getBody()->getContents());
    
    // Send mail to registrant
  }
}
```

Full working example:

```
// Connect to API
$client = new Client(
    [
        'debug' => false,
        'base_uri' => 'https://api.combell.com',
        'combell_api_key' => 'XXXXX',
        'combell_api_secret' => 'XXXXX'
    ]
);
// Get domains from API
$domainsobj = $client->get('/v2/domains/');
$domains = json_decode($domainsobj->getBody()->getContents());

// Get domains that need to be renewed
foreach ($domains as $domain) {
  // Get expiration date of each domain
  $expirationdate = new \DateTime($domain->expiration_date);

  // Calculate Send date (= 31 days prior to expiration)
  $senddate = $expirationdate->sub(new \DateInterval("P31D"));
  $senddate = $senddate->format("Y-m-d");
  
  // Set the current date
  $currentdate = new \DateTime("now");
  $currentdate = $currentdate->format("Y-m-d");
  
  // Send mail to registrant
  if ($senddate == $currentdate) {

    // Get expiring domains from API
    $expiringdomainobj = $client->get('/v2/domains/' . $domain->domain_name);
    $expiringdomain = json_decode($expiringdomainobj->getBody()->getContents());
  
    $date = new \DateTime($expiringdomain->expiration_date);
    $date = $date->format("Y-m-d");

    $domain = $expiringdomain->domain_name;

    $mail = $expiringdomain->registrant->email;

    SendMail ($date, $mail, $domain);

  }
  
}
```

Please note:

- I have no hand in the API so I can't change it
- These endpoints don't accept multiple parameters

There must be a better way to handle this. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Working solutions that need refactoring might be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @El_Vanja I added a full working example as in favor of your comment.

Comment: My comment was to point out a potentially better site for the question. How did you read that as "add a full working example"?

Comment: Nevermind, but I did. Haven't heard of Code Review, all new to this. Will have a look there. Thanks.